# Use PractRand with Java Jar

Tags: java, random

I am trying to use PractRand to test the output of my RandomNumberGenerator. My understanding is that PractRand can read bytes from the StdIn.

```
public class App {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    RandomNumberGenerator rng = new RandomNumberGenerator();
    rng.initiateRandomGenerator();

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
            List<Integer> output = rng.draw(0, 9, 1);
            byte num = output.get(0).byteValue();
            System.out.write(num);
        }

  }
}
```

And then `java -jar target/rng-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar | ~/Downloads/PractRand/RNG_test stdin64`

The above fails however with `Segmetation fault` given from PractRand. Apparently I am doing something incorrectly but I don't know what.  A cpp program that could work is

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdint>

#include <random>

int main()
{
freopen(NULL, "wb", stdout);  // Only necessary on Windows, but harmless. 

std::mt19937_64 rng(42);
constexpr size_t BUFFER_SIZE = 1024 * 1024 / sizeof(uint64_t);
static uint64_t buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

while (1) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < BUFFER_SIZE; ++i)
        buffer[i] = rng();
    fwrite((void*) buffer, sizeof(buffer[0]), BUFFER_SIZE, stdout);
}
}
```

So I guess the `fwrite` in cpp is different to what I am doing in Java. How though?

Comment: "I guess" don't guess: pipe the output of the program into something like xxd, see if the output matches what you intend

Comment: PractRand? Are we supposed to know what that is? Clearly the C++ code is writing the 2**20=1048576 random bytes out in binary while your Java program is writing out the 1000000 byte random numbers out as signed decimal values between -128 and +127. This should have been noticeable with a minimal effort.